# Как сделать так, чтобы замена ошибок была для каждого случая своя?

Tags: python

мой код, не работает замена второй ошибки.

```
loop = True
while loop:
    try:
        x=int(input('Введите число 1: '))
        y=int(input('Введите число 2: '))
        loop = False
    except ValueError:
        print('Ошибка, введите число!')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Ошибка, на ноль делить нельзя!')
print(x/y)
```

Comment: не работает, потому что деление происходит за пределами блока try..except. Понятно дело, что если в try нет деления на 0, то оно и не отловится.

Answer (score 3):

Добавьте еще одну проверку:

```
if y == 0: raise ZeroDivisionError           # +++
```

---

```
loop = True

while loop:
    try:
        x=int(input('Введите число 1: '))
        y=int(input('Введите число 2: '))
        
        if y == 0: raise ZeroDivisionError           # +++
        
        loop = False
    except ValueError:
        print('Ошибка, введите число!')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Ошибка, на ноль делить нельзя!')
        
print(x/y)
```

Comment: При вычислении `x/y` исключение само выкинется. Надо только правильно выстроить код, чтобы его тоже поймать.

Answer (score 3):

```
loop = True
while loop:
    try:
        x=int(input('Введите число 1: '))
        y=int(input('Введите число 2: '))
        print(x/y)
        loop = False
    except ValueError:
        print('Ошибка, введите число!')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Ошибка, на ноль делить нельзя!')
```

Деление происходит за пределами отлавливаемого исключения, вариант выше рабочий

Comment: Если `y` равно `0` - вы выходите из цикла, чего делать, как я понимаю не надо.

Comment: Значит, надо переставить местами присвоение `loop` и `print` )

Comment: ну да, цикл должен начаться заново с запроса

Comment: @S.Nick исправил

Answer (score 2):

Наиболее красиво будет вот так выглядеть, мне кажется. Переменная для управления циклом тут лишняя:

```
while True:
    try:
        x=int(input('Введите число 1: '))
        y=int(input('Введите число 2: '))
        print(x/y)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Ошибка, введите число!')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Ошибка, на ноль делить нельзя!')
```

По-хорошему, конечно, исключения на первом `int(input(` и на втором надо отдельно обрабатывать, чтобы не вводить всё время первое число, когда ошибка только на втором, но это уже громоздко будет выглядеть. Если только в отдельную функцию выносить. В общем, можно и дальше совершенствовать.